# How to implement a task scheduler service using Quartz.net for multiple servers?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, quartz.net

I want to implement Task Scheduler using Quartz.Net on WCF service which have following requirement,

- should be WCF service.
- **hosted on multiple server on multiple location.**
- **execute only once though that scheduler service is running on multiple server for particular time.**
- history can be maintained through any kind of database.
- can execute any kind of job like .exe file, image file, particular task, any kind of command, sql queries, etc.
- **I'm just trying to work out if it's possible to use the quartz scheduler across multiple servers, all pointing at the same database.**
- **Also my main motivation for this is for a fail-over mechanism, but also to spread the load.**

I have little bit knowledge about Quartz.Net and I have created on test sample and also I search for more details that how Quartz.net actually execute on system, how Quartz.net users memory, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for the wcf part, all of your issues above can be solved through Quartz.Net. Just install the service on all the servers you need. Configure them all as clustered and point them at the same database. This covers most of your items.

You can make a WCF wrapper if you want to communicate with Quartz.Net directly, as it only supports remoting out of the box.

You can write a job listener to log job history.

Running executables is supported out of the box. For the other types of jobs you'll have to create your own custom job.

Comment: Hi @jvilalta 
Please can you give me some ready-mate code or some references so i can make my application ASAP. Cause i want to implement this service ASAP. Please help me out. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Clustering: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_11.html
JobHistoryListener: http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2010/11/creating-quartznet-joblistener.html