# How to create DateTimePicker in Razor MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, datetimepicker, quartz.net

I am creating a web-based task scheduling application using QUARTZ.NET and RAZOR(MVC4).
For more details [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802755/how-to-implement-a-task-scheduler-service-using-quartz-net-for-multiple-servers/15854689?noredirect=1#15854689) as given bellow

[image: Form to add scheduler]

Please give me some code or any reference to implement DateTimePicker in RAZOR(MVC4).

**Thanks for your precious Help in Advance.**

Comment: The question seems rather really obvious to me! I was looking also for an answer to this question. Maybe you should approach the question as being a jUNIOR and not as a Senior Developer :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this basic blog for datepicker with jquery UI.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1

See my extending blog for localization support
http://locktar.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/localization-validation-in-mvc/

Comment: Hi and Thanks @LockTar
i tried this but this implementation gives only date not time. My main aim to implement task scheduler and in task scheduler time is equally imp with date. So please help me with some implementation or code.

<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, "datePicker", "datePicker")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>

Comment: I think it is better to do the time in a separate textbox. There is no editor to do the date and time the same time.

Comment: Thanks @LockTar for your comment. This is the last option to do.
Thanks for Help. :)

Answer (score 0):

from the model set the field to datetime

```
public DateTime myDate { get; set; }
//View
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myDate)
```

Comment: Hi comb, i tried this but it will not work as i required. So please help me with some implementation or code.

'<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDateTime)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDateTime)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDateTime)
        </div>
'
Also one class
'
public class JobDetail
{
public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
}
'